# Generating a random four digit pin, last digit is always zero

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to generate a four digit pin code, between 0000 and 9999 using Javascript. I've had the problem that naturally, numbers like 403 will be generated, so everything is prefixed with 0 and then I use `substr` to get the last four digits.

For some reason, the last number is always zero, and I have no idea why:

```
function generatePin () {
    min = 0,
    max = 9999;
    return ("0" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min).substr(-4);
}
```

The output from running it 10 times is:

```
2200
1070
9370
4870
5190
5490
5240
7410
1190
0220
2310
```

Answer (score 5):

It's ending with a 0 because at the end of your number you have `+ min`, and `min` is 0. It's performing string concatenation, not integer addition, so you're tacking on a zero to the end. Just remove that bit and it will fix the issue.

And Buck Doyle (pardon the fact that I don't know how to link to a user) is quite right -- if you're going to parse the whole thing as a string, you'll need some more leading zeroes. Three zeroes out front will give you a four-digit string even if you randomized a 1.

Comment: And this is why you must be careful when using languages like PHP and Javascript where anything can be be a string, or not be a string, depending on the context. Personally, I *hate* automatic string conversion.

Comment: Also, you should add `"000"` to the string, because the random number could be single-digit.

Answer (score 5):

```
Math.random().toString().substr(2,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pair of brackets to surpass this.

```
function generatePin () {
    min = 0,
    max = 9999;
    return ("0" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min)).substr(-4);
}
```

" + min " was causing the trailing zero to append.